# HTML5 canvas issue when I test on mobile's browser

Tags: javascript, error-handling, html5-canvas, mobile-browser, animate-cc

I'm working on an Animate cc project. to make an HTML5 canvas page.
The issue will appear when I see the page on my **mobile's browser**. the issue is when I click any buttons in it then a **blue transparent overlay** will appear on all around of the screen and suddenly disappear. I searched about it on the internet but I couldn't find an answer to fix it. you can check the issue from the following address(please check it on your mobile browser):

[My apps link](https://globalwdf.000webhostapp.com/html5Works/HTML5_language_lessons/en/en_unit1_html5_vocabulary.html)

This is the codes that I used for it clicks event:

```
thisMc=this;

dialogsArr=[thisMc.ivanDialog,thisMc.akilDialog,thisMc.xiaDialog,thisMc.maxDialog,thisMc.mariaDialog,thisMc.observeTxt];
//disapear dialogs
function disapearDialogs()
{
    dialogsArr[0].alpha=0;
    dialogsArr[1].alpha=0;
    dialogsArr[2].alpha=0;
    dialogsArr[3].alpha=0;
    dialogsArr[4].alpha=0;
    dialogsArr[5].alpha=0;
}
disapearDialogs();
dialogsArr[5].alpha=1;

//persons events
thisMc.ivanBtn.on('click', function()
{
    createjs.Sound.stop();
    disapearDialogs();

    createjs.Sound.play('my_name_is_ivan');
    dialogsArr[0].alpha=1;
    stage.update();
});

thisMc.akilBtn.on('click', function()
{
    createjs.Sound.stop();
    disapearDialogs();

    createjs.Sound.play('my_name_is_akil');
    dialogsArr[1].alpha=1;
    stage.update();
});

thisMc.xiaBtn.on('click', function()
{
    createjs.Sound.stop();
    disapearDialogs();

    createjs.Sound.play('my_name_is_xia');
    dialogsArr[2].alpha=1;
    stage.update();
});

thisMc.maxBtn.on('click', function()
{
    createjs.Sound.stop();
    disapearDialogs();

    createjs.Sound.play('my_name_is_max');
    dialogsArr[3].alpha=1;
    stage.update();
});

thisMc.mariaBtn.on('click', function()
{
    createjs.Sound.stop();
    disapearDialogs();

    createjs.Sound.play('my_name_is_maria');
    dialogsArr[4].alpha=1;
    stage.update();
});
```

I wondered if anyone knows how to fix this issue. 
Please let me know if you know anything about it.

Thank you very much.

Tom

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions are expected to have the minimal code to reproduce the issue. Please read [ask] and take a [tour]

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your message. If I didn't place codes in this question because I think it's not my code's problem. I used a simple code for the click event. but OK I will place some of its codes too. Thanks